# Group scatterplot by colour from dictionary in matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a dictionary of data that I would like to plot. My dictionary is currently structured like so: (# = some number)

```
data = { '15': [{'x': #, 'y': #}, {'x': #, 'y': #}, etc..], '16': [{'x': #, 'y': #}, {'x': #, 'y': #}, etc..], '17': [{'x': #, 'y': #}, {'x': #, 'y': #}, etc..] }
```

I am currently looping over each of the key values in the dict and appending the x and y values to a x and y array then plotting x and y

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I would like to still plot all these x and y points but colour/seperate the points by which key they came from.

For this example dict I would like to have a legend on the plot with the points of different colour with the categories being: '15', '16', '17'

Ive looked up some resources online specifically this link: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-color-a-scatter-plot-by-category-using-matplotlib-in-python

and tried separating like so but I dont think this is the right direction:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.DataFrame.groupby(list(data.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, this should answer your question

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

data = {'A': [{'x': 1, 'y' : 2}, {'x': 2, 'y' : 3}, {'x': 3, 'y' : 4}], 'B': [{'x': 5, 'y' : 6}, {'x': 6, 'y' : 7}, {'x': 7, 'y' : 8}], 'C': [{'x': 10, 'y' : 11}, {'x': 11, 'y' : 12}, {'x': 12, 'y' : 13}]}
x, y, group = [], [], []
for i in data:
    for j in data[i]:
        x.append(j['x'])
        y.append(j['y'])
        group.append(i)
        
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sns.scatterplot(x = x, y = y, hue = group)
plt.savefig("fig.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]